# Large numbers of update performance

Tags: sql-server

I have the following update statement below:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
SET [originaldate] =
CASE
    WHEN [datecolumn1] <= [datecolumn2] THEN datecolumn3 
    ELSE [datecolumn1] 
END
```

This statement executed for almost 5 minutes for 2.6 million of rows. Is there any way to optimize this query?

I tried converting the columns to `date` like this `CONVERT(date, [datecolumn2])` because the columns are `datetime` but still the execution time is the same.

Also, i tried putting the column and id that I needed in a temp table but still the performance is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Why does it matter if it takes time?  This does not seem like something you should be doing regularly.

If it is then you should consider using a [computed column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx)

or even in application logic, a view or in the `SELECT` statement depending on the situation.

Comment: A small example for a computed column would be great inside your answer. Referral to a link alone is not a real good answer (even though I admit it constitutes some form of an answer). Read more about this viewpoint [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/273645).

Answer (score 0):

Updating all the rows in a table takes time because of logging and transaction overhead.  You might find this faster:

```
select t.*
into #temp
from mytable;

truncate table mytable;

insert into mytable(col1, . . ., originaldate)
    select . . ., 
           (CASE WHEN [datecolumn1] <= [datecolumn2] THEN datecolumn3 
                 ELSE [datecolumn1] 
            END)
    from #temp;
```

Comment: Maybe you can state some situation cannot use this, for example, it have key constraint, or have the auto increment field (need to turn off the identity), thanks.

Comment: I can give this a try but my concern are the constraints and identity. Also, there are plenty of columns in my table.

Comment: @GeraldGonzales . . . The identity requires fiddling with `identity_insert`.  Constraints depend on their nature.